# playground/application command shortcut different behavior

Tags: qooxdoo

sorry my english. Hi

check this little example

[Playground example](http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/playground/#%7B%22code%22%3A%22function%2520createRandomRows(rowCount)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520var%2520rowData%2520%253D%2520%255B%255D%253B%250A%2520%2520var%2520now%2520%253D%2520new%2520Date().getTime()%253B%250A%2520%2520var%2520dateRange%2520%253D%2520400%2520*%252024%2520*%252060%2520*%252060%2520*%25201000%253B%2520%252F%252F%2520400%2520days%250A%2520%2520var%2520nextId%2520%253D%25200%253B%250A%2520%2520for%2520(var%2520row%2520%253D%25200%253B%2520row%2520%253C%2520rowCount%253B%2520row%252B%252B)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520date%2520%253D%2520new%2520Date(now%2520%252B%2520Math.random()%2520*%2520dateRange%2520-%2520dateRange%2520%252F%25202)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520rowData.push(%255B%2520nextId%252B%252B%252C%2520Math.random()%2520*%252010000%252C%2520date%252C%2520(Math.random()%2520%253E%25200.5)%2520%255D)%253B%250A%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520return%2520rowData%253B%250A%257D%250A%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520window%250Avar%2520win%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.window.Window(%2522Table%2522).set(%257B%250A%2520%2520layout%2520%253A%2520new%2520qx.ui.layout.Grow()%252C%250A%2520%2520allowClose%253A%2520false%252C%250A%2520%2520allowMinimize%253A%2520false%252C%250A%2520%2520contentPadding%253A%25200%250A%257D)%253B%250Athis.getRoot().add(win)%253B%250Awin.moveTo(30%252C%252040)%253B%250Awin.open()%253B%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520table%2520model%250Avar%2520tableModel%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.table.model.Simple()%253B%250AtableModel.setColumns(%255B%2520%2522ID%2522%252C%2520%2522A%2520number%2522%252C%2520%2522A%2520date%2522%252C%2520%2522Boolean%2522%2520%255D)%253B%250AtableModel.setData(createRandomRows(1000))%253B%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520make%2520second%2520column%2520editable%250AtableModel.setColumnEditable(1%252C%2520true)%253B%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520table%250Avar%2520table%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.table.Table(tableModel).set(%257B%250A%2520%2520decorator%253A%2520null%250A%257D)%253B%250Awin.add(table)%253B%250A%250Avar%2520tcm%2520%253D%2520table.getTableColumnModel()%253B%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520Display%2520a%2520checkbox%2520in%2520column%25203%250Atcm.setDataCellRenderer(3%252C%2520new%2520qx.ui.table.cellrenderer.Boolean())%253B%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520use%2520a%2520different%2520header%2520renderer%250Atcm.setHeaderCellRenderer(2%252C%2520new%2520qx.ui.table.headerrenderer.Icon(%2522icon%252F16%252Fapps%252Foffice-calendar.png%2522%252C%2520%2522A%2520date%2522))%253B%250A%250A%250A%250A%250A%250A%250Avar%2520commandEscape%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.command.Command(%2522Escape%2522)%253B%250AcommandEscape.addListener(%2522execute%2522%252C%2520function(e)%257B%250A%2509if%2520(!%2520table.isEditing())%2520this.debug(%2522escape%2522)%253B%250A%257D)%253B%22%2C%20%22mode%22%3A%22ria%22%7D)

Go to table, start edition of some cell, then press Escape, and press Escape again:
the edition cancel, and the command's execute listener work fine.
All is Ok.

Now copy this example to blank new Qooxdoo 5.0.2 application, run and edit a cell.
The behavior change: the command completely nullifies the table's keypress listener when I press Escape key.

What is good, what is bad?

If I change the line

```
if (! table.isEditing()) this.debug("escape");
```

to

```
if (! table.isEditing()) {
    this.debug("escape")
} else {
    table.cancelEditing();
    table.focus();
}
```

the behavior is reasonable. 
But I want the Playground behavior. And I want understand, because when I subclass table widget and interact with several commands I get similar problems.

I'm doing something wrong? How can solutionate this differente behavior?
Im using Firefox 49 and Windows 8.1.
Thanks

Comment: I would expect the 'second' behaviour since commands are global, so they should have preference. But I have not investigated the playground source for the root cause of this difference in behavior ...

Comment: yes, I agree. But my big problem I think is the table's keypress event disappearance. Why this? This is good? Thanks